# How to setup mail when using iCloud plus 2 external mail accounts

Tags: ios, icloud, email

I believe that as a user of 2 iMacs , 1 iphones and one iPad the best is to use my xx@me.com  account on iCloud as main account and alias my other external accounts to xx@me.com
The 2 external accounts are pol@myname.lu     and po1@myname.eu

Can anybody confirm this approach or tell me what's better?!
Thanks all!
Pol

Answer (score 1):

What I do is forward my other mail accounts to my @me.com address.

Comment: Sounds like what I planned to do .This brings the follow-up question:  can I still use my external (non iCloud( adresses for outgoing mails?

Comment: Unfortunately it only lets you send using the primary address, not the ones you forward to it.

Comment: Of course you can! Setup mail forwarding for the two additional accounts but create mail accounts in Mail.app for them as well. All incoming mail will be in the me.com account, for replies/new mails you can select the account you want to send the mail from.